# Cant Bundle Install on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, bundler, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

It seems like whenever I do a git aws.push to my rails app it doesn't do a bundle install.

AWS shows this in the logs:

### 2014-04-29 15:36:44 UTC+1000 INFO Command execution completed. Summary: [Successful: 0, TimedOut: 1]. 2014-04-29 15:36:44 UTC+1000 WARN The following instances have not responded in the allowed command timeout time (they might still finish eventually on their own): [i-5cf23562].

I suspect that the optionsettings file is not working. It seems like aws.push pushes the files into the ondeck folder but the bundler stops there. I can also keep doing aws.push over and over and it never says I've already pushed the latest commit.

How do I get bundle install working after a push and get my code automatically moved from ondeck to current?

I'm very new to AWS so there is maybe something obvious I've missed out here.

Comment: Ok for some reason I can bundle now but still whenever I do a git aws.push, the terminal says the push works and I can see stuff being uploaded BUT nothing is changing in the actual code if I ssh into the EC2 instance and look at both ondeck and current, the code is the same as before the push. When I wait for the server to stop updating and push again, the exact same code is being pushed up all over again.

Comment: Make sure your server can access the internet. If you have setup your instance inside VPC, you may be able to SSH into it (incoming connection) using some method but the instance will also need to access S3 bucket (outgoing connections) where your code is stored (aws.push basically puts your code in a bucket for an instance to fetch)

Comment: I can SSH into it. I should have clarified that was the only way I could run a bundle install by going inside the instance and doing bundle install and migrate inside it.

Comment: You may be able to SSH into it. That is an inbound connection for your server. Can you do something like "wget yahoo.com" from the instance?